# Sklar's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Does Sklar's theorem basically say that any arbitrary joint probability distribution of $N$ random variables can be 'normalized' by mapping it onto a joint distribution over an $N$-dimensional unit cube with uniform marginal distributions over $[0,1]^N$?

Comment: This is a rather straightforward conclusion of the quantile transform. I didn't know it has a name, but yes, the meaning is this.

Comment: OK, I believe you...but if it is a rather straightforward result, why did it take until 1959 for it to be called out and proven?

Comment: I believe the Sklar's theorem *main* point is the converse: an arbitrary joint probability distribution is *defined* by (*i*) a copula, i.e. a uniform-marginal joint distribution, and (*ii*) a set of marginals, which may be non-uniform. In other words, any distribution can be "un-normalised" from its "normalised" joint, and the original marginals is precisely what you need. I share your surprise about copula being a late child, but 1960s is only ~30 years since Kolmogorov's probability axioms of 1930s, which is just 1/3 longer than between now and Web 2.0.